# How to debug SQLDataSource update command?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Visual Studio 2010 is there a way to step through the Update Command of a SQLDataSource?

I have the SQLDataSource and the parameters specified on the *.aspx  It's using a Stored Procedure.

I'm getting a "has too many arguments specified" error.  The number of parameters I've specified exactly match the stored proc.  So, I'd love to be able to debug and see what arguments the SQLDataSource is trying to send.

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPDATE_TABLEA]
    --UPDATE
    @ID int,
    @COL1 varchar(200),
    @COL2 varchar(200),
    @COL3 varchar(20),
    @COL4 varchar(100),
    @COL5 varchar(100),
    @COL6 varchar(10),
    @COL7 varchar(200),
    @COL8 datetime,
    @COL9 datetime,
    @COL10 varchar(20),
    @COL11 datetime,
    @COL12 varchar(20),
    @COL13 datetime,    
    --INSERT TRANSACTION
    @COL14 varchar(100)

AS

BEGIN
    --UPDATE
    UPDATE TABLEA SET 
        COL1 = @COL1,
        COL2 = @COL2,
        COL3 = @COL3,
        COL4 = @COL4,
        COL5 = @COL5,
        COL6 = @COL6,
        COL7 = @COL7,
        COL8 = @COL8,
        COL9 = @COL9,
        COL10 = @COL10,
        COL11 = @COL11,
        COL12 = @COL12,
        COL13 = @COL13,
        COL15 = (SELECT COLX FROM TABLE WHERE [COLY] = 'ASDF')
    WHERE ID = @ID

    --ADD TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO TABLEB ([COL1], [COL2], id, [datetime]) VALUES (@COL14, (SELECT COLX FROM TABLE WHERE [COLY] = 'ASDF'), @ID, GETDATE())
END
```

My SQLDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds1" runat="server" 
            ...
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE_TABLEA" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"             
            ...
        >
            <UpdateParameters>    
                <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="@ID" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="200" Name="@COL1" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="200" Name="@COL2" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="20" Name="@COL3" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="100" Name="@COL4" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="100" Name="@COL5" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="10" Name="@COL6" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="200" Name="@COL7" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="DateTime" Name="@COL8" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="DateTime" Name="@COL9" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="20" Name="@COL10" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="DateTime" Name="@COL11" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="20" Name="@COL12" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="DateTime" Name="@COL13" Direction="Input" />
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Size="100" Name="@COL14" DefaultValue="<%=user_id%>" Direction="Input" />
            </UpdateParameters>
```

Here's the SQL Profiler Output:

```
exec UPDATE_TABLEA @@ID=NULL,@@COL1=NULL,@@COL2=NULL,@@COL3=NULL,@@COL4=NULL,@@COL5=NULL,@@COL6=NULL,@@COL7=NULL,@@COL8=NULL,@@COL9=NULL,@@COL10=NULL,@@COL11=NULL,@@COL12=NULL,@@COL13=NULL,@@COL14=N'<%=user_id%>',@ID=1
```

The last 2 params look odd.  Not sure why though...

Any ideas...why it's telling me too many arguments?

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL Server? If so, you could try SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the @ in my parameter definitions.

Doesn't work:

```
<asp:Parameter Type="DateTime" Name="@COL11" Direction="Input" />
```

Works:

```
<asp:Parameter Type="DateTime" Name="COL11" Direction="Input" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The SqlDataSource is in an EditItemTemplate. That means there'll be a SqlDataSource for each row of this GridView, Repeater—whatever this is.

If you want to get the SqlDataSource for, say, the third row in your GridView, you'd want something like:

Code behind:

```
SqlDataSource sqlSource = gv.Rows[2].FindControl("sqlId") as SqlDataSource;
Response.Write(sqlSource.ConnectionString);
```

Now check the parameters for this SqlDataSource.